# Getting error: GET https://www.gstatic.com/charts/elements/loader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is: And I am getting the error GET https://www.gstatic.com/charts/elements/loader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404.Please help me to sort out this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
// Load the Google Transliterate API
google.charts.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "transliteration"
});
function onLoad()
{
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage: 'en',
        // destinationLanguage: ['hi', 'bn', 'kn', 'ml', 'mr', 'ne', 'or', 'fa', 'pa', 'sa', 'ta', 'te', 'ur'],
        destinationLanguage: ['hi', 'mr', 'bn', 'gu', 'pa', 'ur'],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: false
    };
    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
    // show control on multiple input
    //var ids = [ "transl1", "ad_matter" ];
    var ids = ["editordiv"];
    control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
    // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
    // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
    control.showControl('translControl');
    //  control.c.qc.t13n.c[3].c.d.keyup[0].ia.F.p = 'https://www.google.com';
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into what a [404 status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) is. The link you're using is either dead or incorrect.

Are you perhaps looking for https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js? From [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) page on Google Chart's guide?